# Best way to manage resources(Not necessarily RESX files) in .Net solution

Tags: c#, .net, resources, filesystems

This sounded like a trivial question initially but I did not come across any solid/best practice solution on how to do this so I am asking the question here. Now, let's imagine that we have to work with couple of **".txt"** files in our code which is in a class library.

Now, I think there are 3 major ways to handle this:

- **Just put everything in your Bin/Debug/Resources folder** of the calling application and in your code use "Resources\*.txt". I think this is the simplest and most unobtrusive way to handle this. However, there are many trivial problems with it:

  - When you check in the source control would not check-in the files inside the Bin/Debug folder
  - So in this case, probably adding the folder one level above and then writting post-build scripts is the most efficient option I guess?
- **Add resources folder on the same level as Bin folder**. That way we can successfully manage it using the source control. however now when we need to reference it through our code it becomes tricky

  - We can reference this files assuming that the Binary folder's structure is like Bin/Debug and reference to the Resources folder like ..\..\Resources
  - **But** this structure is not always guaranteed  what if the binary folder structure is like Bin/ (without any debug folder in it) then ../../Resources is going to fail
- Add all the txt files as **.RESX** files. But I am not sure if it is the practice around everywhere and the most popular way to store resources.

  -Also, the code that we have to write to access the resources files sounds like cumbersome as oppose to just picking up the file from windows file system.

Probably I am missing something trivial but I was just curious and was thinking that it should be much more simpler than this. Any suggestions?

Comment: As for solution 1, if you want text files to be part of your deployment/installation then this is a valid approach. Not sure what you mean by "much simpler".

Comment: If you are writing to these files, they should be stored in the Application Data directory, and placed there during the installation. Don't expect your application will have write permissions for the directory (or sub directories) its contained in.

Comment: I meant if I want to go with solution 1 then I will end up writing post-build commands. Is it a clean standard practice?

Comment: @RonBeyer: I am simply reading from it

Comment: @CoffeeBean *Also, the code that we have to write to access the resources files*, sounds to me like read/write from what you wrote in the question.

Comment: Would adding files normally and set "copy to output folder" solve your problem?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:"Copy to output folder" using post-build?

Comment: @CoffeeBean no, I mean just set property of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different project in the solution called Myproject.Resources.
Next install Microsoft MAT and manage your translations with MAT: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit

You manage your translations with MAT and the .resx files are kept up-to-date. ;-)